# CocoaLumberjack - change log file name by subclassing the LogFileManager

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, carthage, cocoalumberjack

I am trying to change the logfile name. What i've found so far is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857508/cocoalumberjack-ios-can-we-change-the-logfile-name-and-directory).

My subclass of DDLogFileManagerDefault looks like this:

LogFileManager.h

```
@import CocoaLumberjack;

// this import would work as well
// #import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h> 

// but none of these
//#import "DDLog.h"
//#import "DDTTYLogger.h"
//#import "DDASLLogger.h"
//#import "DDFileLogger.h"

@interface LogFileManager : DDLogFileManagerDefault

@end
```

LogFileManager.m

```
#import "LogFileManager.h"

@implementation LogFileManager

- (NSString *)newLogFileName {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSDictionary *info = [bundle infoDictionary];
    NSString *appName = [info objectForKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"];

    NSString *timeStamp = [self getTimestamp];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.log", appName, timeStamp];
}

- (BOOL)isLogFile:(NSString *)fileName {
    return NO;
}

- (NSString *)getTimestamp {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY.MM.dd-HH.mm.ss"];
    });

    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:NSDate.date];
}

@end
```

This is how I use it:

```
DDLogFileManagerDefault *documentsFileManager = [[LogFileManager alloc] init];    
DDFileLogger *fileLogger = [[DDFileLogger alloc] initWithLogFileManager:documentsFileManager];
```

When I replace `LogFileManager` with `DDLogFileManagerDefault` it works fine. Otherwise I get:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LogFileManager", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in Logger.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

What exactly am I missing here?
CocoaLumberjack is added via Carthage 3.2.0 for Xcode 8.
I've added the `CocoaLumberjack.framework` to the Build Phases like all the other frameworks in the project with `/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks`

Comment: what is `Logger` ?

Comment: Logger is the class where everything is initiated. "This is how I use it" is a part of Logger.m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved it. That error was very confusing but has nothing to do with anything. Sorry for that.

It is a big project with lots of build targets and lots of compile flags that make different things throw a warning and warnings become an error. In this case I added flags to disable the global ones to the mentioned Logger.m class. But I only added those anti-flags to one target and forgot to add them to another. That's why it didn't build.

Still strange, that the compiler didn't simply say: cannot build target A or compile error in file B. Instead I got a missing architecture message that was misleading me totally... So sorry for the trouble. Fixed it.